# Priority Queue<Integer>=k ,does not remove the k where distance[k] is min

Tags: java, priority-queue

```java
int[] distance = new int[100];
PriorityQueue<Integer> pq = new PriorityQueue<>(new Comparator<Integer>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(Integer o1, Integer o2) {
        if (distance[o1] > distance[o2] ) {
            return -1;
        } else if (distance[o1] < distance[o2] ) {
            return 1;
        }
        return 0;
    }
});


for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    distance[i] =new Random().nextInt(100)+1;
    pq.add(i);
}

distance[10]=0;
int u=pq.poll();
```

I thought this comparator should return the element k which distance[k]=MinimumDistance.
Cant Understand why this isn't working..
pq.Poll it's not based on distance[] array.
For example here variable u should be 10.

Comment: Welcome to SO! What exactly is the implementation of `PriorityQueue`? Is it your custom class that you've created ( in this case please add its source code to the question) or its some thirdparty's implementation? In this case add the package, specify the version of third-party jar that you use and consider updating the tags in the question so that the most relevant people could track this question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two issues: Your comparison is reversed. It should be

```
if (distance[o1] > distance[o2] ) {
    return 1;
} else if (distance[o1] < distance[o2] ) {
    return -1;
}
```

Second, you have to set distance[10]=0 before the loop and then not overwrite it. This comparator only comes into play while adding stuff and then you have a random number at position 10.

Comment: Thank y, I thought the PriorityQueue updates itself when is  about to remove.